# Im trying python opencv for finding faces

Tags: python, opencv

I have installed python and opencv.

```
import cv2
```

working fine, but

```
import cv
```

result to

```
ImportError: No module named 'cv2.cv'; 'cv2' is not a package
```

i read that python3 is no more supports cv, but i need it in that code

```
import sys
import cv2
import cv
import numpy
cascPath = "C:\cv/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

def detect(image):
bitmap = cv.fromarray(image)
 faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(bitmap, cascade, cv.CreateMemStorage(0))
 if faces:
  for (x,y,w,h),n in faces:
   pass
   cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),2)
 return image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while 1:
        _,frame =cam.read()
        frame = numpy.asarray(detect(frame))
        cv2.imshow("features", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) == 0x1b: # ESC
            print ('ESC pressed. Exiting ...')
            break
```

Should i try it on python2 or there are ways to do it without cv?
I need to find faces while shooting from webcams.

Comment: try `import cv2 as cv` and change `cv2 to cv` in your code, after import! As far as I remember I think it was `cv2` in `python2.7` also!

Comment: `cv2` supports pretty much everything in `cv` and more.

Comment: didn't help `AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'fromarray' `